# Google Chrome Hosted App disable tab address bar, close other tabs, maximize window

Tags: google-chrome, hosted, google-chrome-app

Some of the tasks we are trying to achieve through Google Chrome Hosted App are as follows.
 Once app is launched,

```
      - the app will close all other tabs.
      - the address bar will be disabled
      - the app will open in maximum size window
```

From my reading of documentation, I believe that it is doable through a packaged app. I think packaged apps are like mobile apps with interfaces to receive and post information. 
 We dont want to create interfaces as such and don't need functionality to work offline.

Some on our development team think that the above functionality could be achieved even with hosted app but don't know how.

I am stuck with this riddle for quite some time. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a packaged app is what you want. Hosted apps cannot disable the address bar. They can manipulate tabs, but that's a poor user experience - I would take a look at the packaged apps approach.